# Complex bind columns (using dplyr to re-organize the data with left_join and bind cols)

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

I have this dataset (example). If you notice, the **first and second columns are descriptive and will not change**. The **third, fourth, and fifth** columns have dynamic values (but also dynamic column names). Then, the **sixth, seventh, and eight** columns, then the **ninth tenth eleventh** columns value dynamic values and so on. (In the real dataset, I have more than 1.000 columns)

[image: dataset]

In sum, from some point on, every three columns have the same information.

I'm trying to have a final dataset with 5 columns, in which the first two columns will be "fine motor" and "skill". The third, fourth, and fifth will gather all other values and place them below.

The image below shows how the final dataset should be:

[image: final]

Any help is valuable. Please use this code below (and I'll be happy to remain within tidyverse framework)

```
ds <- structure(list(fine_motor = c("2.2", "2.2"), skill = c("B. Functional Use", 
"A. Reach, Grab, Release"), spread_sheet_id_3 = c(1, 1), score_s_4 = c(2, 
2), confirm_s_5 = c("Meets", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_7 = c(2, 
2), score_s_8 = c(2, 2), confirm_s_9 = c("Meets", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_11 = c(3, 
3), score_s_12 = c(2, 2), confirm_s_13 = c("Meets", "Meets"), 
    spread_sheet_id_15 = c(4, 4), score_s_16 = c(1, 2), confirm_s_17 = c("Inconsistent", 
    "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_19 = c(5, 5), score_s_20 = c(1, 
    2), confirm_s_21 = c("Inconsistent", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_23 = c(6, 
    6), score_s_24 = c(2, 2), confirm_s_25 = c("Meets", "Meets"
    ), spread_sheet_id_27 = c(7, 7), score_s_28 = c(0, 1), confirm_s_29 = c("Does Not", 
    "Inconsistent"), spread_sheet_id_31 = c(8, 8), score_s_32 = c(2, 
    2), confirm_s_33 = c("Meets", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_35 = c(9, 
    9), score_s_36 = c(1, 2), confirm_s_37 = c("Inconsistent", 
    "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_39 = c(10, 10), score_s_40 = c(2, 
    2), confirm_s_41 = c("Meets", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_43 = c(11, 
    11), score_s_44 = c(0, 2), confirm_s_45 = c("Does Not", "Meets"
    ), spread_sheet_id_47 = c(12, 12), score_s_48 = c(0, 2), 
    confirm_s_49 = c("Does Not", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_51 = c(13, 
    13), score_s_52 = c(2, 2), confirm_s_53 = c("Meets", "Meets"
    ), spread_sheet_id_55 = c(14, 14), score_s_56 = c(2, 2), 
    confirm_s_57 = c("Meets", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_59 = c(15, 
    15), score_s_60 = c(2, 2), confirm_s_61 = c("Meets", "Meets"
    ), spread_sheet_id_63 = c(16, 16), score_s_64 = c(2, 2), 
    confirm_s_65 = c("Meets", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_67 = c(17, 
    17), score_s_68 = c(2, 2), confirm_s_69 = c("Meets", "Meets"
    ), spread_sheet_id_71 = c(18, 18), score_s_72 = c(2, 2), 
    confirm_s_73 = c("Meets", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_75 = c(19, 
    19), score_s_76 = c(2, 2), confirm_s_77 = c("Meets", "Meets"
    ), spread_sheet_id_79 = c(20, 20), score_s_80 = c(1, 2), 
    confirm_s_81 = c("Inconsistent", "Meets"), spread_sheet_id_83 = c(21, 
    21), score_s_84 = c(0, 2), confirm_s_85 = c("Does Not", "Meets"
    ), spread_sheet_id_87 = c(22, 22), score_s_88 = c(0, 1), 
    confirm_s_89 = c("Does Not", "Inconsistent"), spread_sheet_id_91 = c(23, 
    23), score_s_92 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_93 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"
    ), spread_sheet_id_95 = c(24, 24), score_s_96 = c(0, 0), 
    confirm_s_97 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_99 = c(25, 
    25), score_s_100 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_101 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_103 = c(26, 26), score_s_104 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_105 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_107 = c(27, 
    27), score_s_108 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_109 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_111 = c(28, 28), score_s_112 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_113 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_115 = c(29, 
    29), score_s_116 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_117 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_119 = c(30, 30), score_s_120 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_121 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_123 = c(31, 
    31), score_s_124 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_125 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_127 = c(32, 32), score_s_128 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_129 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_131 = c(33, 
    33), score_s_132 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_133 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_135 = c(34, 34), score_s_136 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_137 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_139 = c(35, 
    35), score_s_140 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_141 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_143 = c(36, 36), score_s_144 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_145 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_147 = c(37, 
    37), score_s_148 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_149 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_151 = c(38, 38), score_s_152 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_153 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_155 = c(39, 
    39), score_s_156 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_157 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_159 = c(40, 40), score_s_160 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_161 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_163 = c(41, 
    41), score_s_164 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_165 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_167 = c(42, 42), score_s_168 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_169 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_171 = c(43, 
    43), score_s_172 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_173 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_175 = c(44, 44), score_s_176 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_177 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_179 = c(45, 
    45), score_s_180 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_181 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_183 = c(46, 46), score_s_184 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_185 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_187 = c(47, 
    47), score_s_188 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_189 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_191 = c(48, 48), score_s_192 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_193 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_195 = c(49, 
    49), score_s_196 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_197 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_199 = c(50, 50), score_s_200 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_201 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_203 = c(51, 
    51), score_s_204 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_205 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_207 = c(52, 52), score_s_208 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_209 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_211 = c(53, 
    53), score_s_212 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_213 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_215 = c(54, 54), score_s_216 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_217 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_219 = c(55, 
    55), score_s_220 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_221 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_223 = c(56, 56), score_s_224 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_225 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_227 = c(57, 
    57), score_s_228 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_229 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_231 = c(58, 58), score_s_232 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_233 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_235 = c(59, 
    59), score_s_236 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_237 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_239 = c(60, 60), score_s_240 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_241 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_243 = c(61, 
    61), score_s_244 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_245 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_247 = c(62, 62), score_s_248 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_249 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_251 = c(63, 
    63), score_s_252 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_253 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_255 = c(64, 64), score_s_256 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_257 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_259 = c(65, 
    65), score_s_260 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_261 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_263 = c(66, 66), score_s_264 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_265 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_267 = c(67, 
    67), score_s_268 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_269 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_271 = c(68, 68), score_s_272 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_273 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_275 = c(69, 
    69), score_s_276 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_277 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_279 = c(70, 70), score_s_280 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_281 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_283 = c(71, 
    71), score_s_284 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_285 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_287 = c(72, 72), score_s_288 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_289 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_291 = c(73, 
    73), score_s_292 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_293 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_295 = c(74, 74), score_s_296 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_297 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_299 = c(75, 
    75), score_s_300 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_301 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_303 = c(76, 76), score_s_304 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_305 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_307 = c(77, 
    77), score_s_308 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_309 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_311 = c(78, 78), score_s_312 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_313 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_315 = c(79, 
    79), score_s_316 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_317 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_319 = c(80, 80), score_s_320 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_321 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_323 = c(81, 
    81), score_s_324 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_325 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_327 = c(82, 82), score_s_328 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_329 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_331 = c(83, 
    83), score_s_332 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_333 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_335 = c(84, 84), score_s_336 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_337 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_339 = c(85, 
    85), score_s_340 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_341 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_343 = c(86, 86), score_s_344 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_345 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_347 = c(87, 
    87), score_s_348 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_349 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_351 = c(88, 88), score_s_352 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_353 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_355 = c(89, 
    89), score_s_356 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_357 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_359 = c(90, 90), score_s_360 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_361 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_363 = c(91, 
    91), score_s_364 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_365 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_367 = c(92, 92), score_s_368 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_369 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_371 = c(93, 
    93), score_s_372 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_373 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_375 = c(94, 94), score_s_376 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_377 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_379 = c(95, 
    95), score_s_380 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_381 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_383 = c(96, 96), score_s_384 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_385 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_387 = c(97, 
    97), score_s_388 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_389 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_391 = c(98, 98), score_s_392 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_393 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_395 = c(99, 
    99), score_s_396 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_397 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_399 = c(100, 100), score_s_400 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_401 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_403 = c(101, 
    101), score_s_404 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_405 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_407 = c(102, 102), score_s_408 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_409 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_411 = c(103, 
    103), score_s_412 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_413 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_415 = c(104, 104), score_s_416 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_417 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_419 = c(105, 
    105), score_s_420 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_421 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_423 = c(106, 106), score_s_424 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_425 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_427 = c(107, 
    107), score_s_428 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_429 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_431 = c(108, 108), score_s_432 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_433 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_435 = c(109, 
    109), score_s_436 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_437 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_439 = c(110, 110), score_s_440 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_441 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_443 = c(111, 
    111), score_s_444 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_445 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_447 = c(112, 112), score_s_448 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_449 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_451 = c(113, 
    113), score_s_452 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_453 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_455 = c(114, 114), score_s_456 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_457 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_459 = c(115, 
    115), score_s_460 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_461 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_463 = c(116, 116), score_s_464 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_465 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_467 = c(117, 
    117), score_s_468 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_469 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_471 = c(118, 118), score_s_472 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_473 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_475 = c(119, 
    119), score_s_476 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_477 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_479 = c(120, 120), score_s_480 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_481 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_483 = c(121, 
    121), score_s_484 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_485 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_487 = c(122, 122), score_s_488 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_489 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_491 = c(123, 
    123), score_s_492 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_493 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_495 = c(124, 124), score_s_496 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_497 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_499 = c(125, 
    125), score_s_500 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_501 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_503 = c(126, 126), score_s_504 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_505 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_507 = c(127, 
    127), score_s_508 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_509 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_511 = c(128, 128), score_s_512 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_513 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_515 = c(129, 
    129), score_s_516 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_517 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_519 = c(130, 130), score_s_520 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_521 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_523 = c(131, 
    131), score_s_524 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_525 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_527 = c(132, 132), score_s_528 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_529 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_531 = c(133, 
    133), score_s_532 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_533 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_535 = c(134, 134), score_s_536 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_537 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_539 = c(135, 
    135), score_s_540 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_541 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_543 = c(136, 136), score_s_544 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_545 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_547 = c(137, 
    137), score_s_548 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_549 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_551 = c(138, 138), score_s_552 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_553 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_555 = c(139, 
    139), score_s_556 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_557 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_559 = c(140, 140), score_s_560 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_561 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_563 = c(141, 
    141), score_s_564 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_565 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_567 = c(142, 142), score_s_568 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_569 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_571 = c(143, 
    143), score_s_572 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_573 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_575 = c(144, 144), score_s_576 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_577 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_579 = c(145, 
    145), score_s_580 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_581 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_583 = c(146, 146), score_s_584 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_585 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_587 = c(147, 
    147), score_s_588 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_589 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_591 = c(148, 148), score_s_592 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_593 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_595 = c(149, 
    149), score_s_596 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_597 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_599 = c(150, 150), score_s_600 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_601 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_603 = c(151, 
    151), score_s_604 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_605 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_607 = c(152, 152), score_s_608 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_609 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_611 = c(153, 
    153), score_s_612 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_613 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_615 = c(154, 154), score_s_616 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_617 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_619 = c(155, 
    155), score_s_620 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_621 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_623 = c(156, 156), score_s_624 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_625 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_627 = c(157, 
    157), score_s_628 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_629 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_631 = c(158, 158), score_s_632 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_633 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_635 = c(159, 
    159), score_s_636 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_637 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_639 = c(160, 160), score_s_640 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_641 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_643 = c(161, 
    161), score_s_644 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_645 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_647 = c(162, 162), score_s_648 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_649 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_651 = c(163, 
    163), score_s_652 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_653 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_655 = c(164, 164), score_s_656 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_657 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_659 = c(165, 
    165), score_s_660 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_661 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_663 = c(166, 166), score_s_664 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_665 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_667 = c(167, 
    167), score_s_668 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_669 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_671 = c(168, 168), score_s_672 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_673 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_675 = c(169, 
    169), score_s_676 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_677 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_679 = c(170, 170), score_s_680 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_681 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_683 = c(171, 
    171), score_s_684 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_685 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_687 = c(172, 172), score_s_688 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_689 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_691 = c(173, 
    173), score_s_692 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_693 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_695 = c(174, 174), score_s_696 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_697 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_699 = c(175, 
    175), score_s_700 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_701 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_703 = c(176, 176), score_s_704 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_705 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_707 = c(177, 
    177), score_s_708 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_709 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_711 = c(178, 178), score_s_712 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_713 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_715 = c(179, 
    179), score_s_716 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_717 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_719 = c(180, 180), score_s_720 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_721 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_723 = c(181, 
    181), score_s_724 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_725 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_727 = c(182, 182), score_s_728 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_729 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_731 = c(183, 
    183), score_s_732 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_733 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_735 = c(184, 184), score_s_736 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_737 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_739 = c(185, 
    185), score_s_740 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_741 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_743 = c(186, 186), score_s_744 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_745 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_747 = c(187, 
    187), score_s_748 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_749 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_751 = c(188, 188), score_s_752 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_753 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_755 = c(189, 
    189), score_s_756 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_757 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_759 = c(190, 190), score_s_760 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_761 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_763 = c(191, 
    191), score_s_764 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_765 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_767 = c(192, 192), score_s_768 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_769 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_771 = c(193, 
    193), score_s_772 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_773 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_775 = c(194, 194), score_s_776 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_777 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_779 = c(195, 
    195), score_s_780 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_781 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_783 = c(196, 196), score_s_784 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_785 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_787 = c(197, 
    197), score_s_788 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_789 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_791 = c(198, 198), score_s_792 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_793 = c("Does Not", "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_795 = c(199, 
    199), score_s_796 = c(0, 0), confirm_s_797 = c("Does Not", 
    "Does Not"), spread_sheet_id_799 = c(200, 200), score_s_800 = c(0, 
    0), confirm_s_801 = c("Does Not", "Does Not")), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want? I used a custom "spec" to define which values from the original format belong in which target columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

# build a pivoting "spec"
spec <- tibble(`.name` = names(ds)) %>%
  slice(-c(1:2)) %>%
  mutate(`.value` = case_when(
           `.name` %>% str_detect("spread") ~ "spread_sheet",
           `.name` %>% str_detect("score")  ~ "score",
           `.name` %>% str_detect("confirm") ~ "confirm")
  )

# apply the spec
ds %>%
  pivot_longer_spec(spec)
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 400 x 5
   fine_motor skill             spread_sheet score confirm     
   <chr>      <chr>                    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>       
 1 2.2        B. Functional Use            1     2 Meets       
 2 2.2        B. Functional Use            2     2 Meets       
 3 2.2        B. Functional Use            3     2 Meets       
 4 2.2        B. Functional Use            4     1 Inconsistent
 5 2.2        B. Functional Use            5     1 Inconsistent
 6 2.2        B. Functional Use            6     2 Meets       
 7 2.2        B. Functional Use            7     0 Does Not    
 8 2.2        B. Functional Use            8     2 Meets       
 9 2.2        B. Functional Use            9     1 Inconsistent
10 2.2        B. Functional Use           10     2 Meets       
# … with 390 more rows
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
ds %>% 
  pivot_longer(-one_of("fine_motor","skill"),
               names_to = c(".value","group"),
               names_sep = "[0-9]+"
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-group)
```

Try now?

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm receiving this message `Expected 2 pieces. Additional pieces discarded in 594 rows`